# zf2 forms and object binding, without clearing non-passed values

Tags: php, zend-form, zend-framework2

I've read through the tutorials/reference of the Form-Component in Zend-Framework 2 and maybe I missed it somehow, so I'm asking here.

I've got an object called `Node` and bound it to a form. I'm using the `Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ArraySerializable`-Standard-Hydrator. So my `Node`-object has got the two methods of `exchangeArray()` and `getArrayCopy()` like this:

```
class Node
{
    public function exchangeArray($data)
    {
        // Standard-Felder
        $this->node_id        = (isset($data['node_id']))   ? $data['node_id']   : null;
        $this->node_name      = (isset($data['node_name'])) ? $data['node_name'] : null;
        $this->node_body      = (isset($data['node_body'])) ? $data['node_body'] : null;
        $this->node_date      = (isset($data['node_date'])) ? $data['node_date'] : null;
        $this->node_image     = (isset($data['node_image'])) ? $data['node_image'] : null;
        $this->node_public    = (isset($data['node_public'])) ? $data['node_public'] : null;
        $this->node_type      = (isset($data['node_type'])) ? $data['node_type']:null;
        $this->node_route      = (isset($data['node_route'])) ? $data['node_route']:null;
    }

    public function getArrayCopy()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

In my Controller I've got an `editAction()`. There I want to modify the values of this `Node`-object. So I am using the `bind`-method of my form. My form has only fields to modify the `node_name` and the `node_body`-property. After validating the form and dumping the `Node`-object after submission of the form the `node_name` and `node_body`-properties now contain the values from the submitted form. However all other fields are empty now, even if they contained initial values before.

```
class AdminController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function editAction()
    {
        // ... more stuff here (getting Node, etc)             

        // Get Form
        $form = $this->_getForm(); // return a \Zend\Form instance
        $form->bind($node); // This is the Node-Object; It contains values for every property

        if(true === $this->request->isPost())
        {
            $data = $this->request->getPost();
            $form->setData($data);

            // Check if form is valid
            if(true === $form->isValid())
            {
                // Dumping here....
                // Here the Node-object only contains values for node_name and node_body all other properties are empty
                echo'<pre>';print_r($node);echo'</pre>';exit;
            }
        }

        // View
        return array(
            'form' => $form,
            'node' => $node,
            'nodetype' => $nodetype
        );
    }
}
```

I want to only overwrite the values which are coming from the form (`node_name` and `node_body`) not the other ones. They should remain untouched.

I think a possible solution would be to give the other properties as hidden fields into the form, however I don't wanna do this.

Is there any possibility to not overwrite values which are not present within the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rechecked the code of \Zend\Form and I gotta be honest I just guessed how I can fix my issue.

The only thing I changed is the Hydrator. It seems that the `Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ArraySerializable` is not intended for my case. Since my `Node`-Object is an object and not an Array I checked the other available hydrators. I've found the `Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty`-hydrator. It works perfectly. Only fields which are available within the form are populated within the bound object. This is exactly what I need. It seems like the `ArraySerializable`-hydrator resets the object-properties, because it calls the `exchangeArray`-method of the bound object (`Node`). And in this method I'm setting the non-given fields to `null` (see code in my question). Another way would propably be to change the `exchangeArray`-method, so that it only sets values if they are not available yet.

So the solution in the code is simple:

```
$form = $this->_getForm();
$form->setHydrator(new \Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty()); // Change default hydrator
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in the class form.php, the filters are not initialized in the bindvalues method just add the line **$filter->setData($this->data);**

it should look like this after including the line

```
public function bindValues(array $values = array())
{
    if (!is_object($this->object)) {
        return;
    }
    if (!$this->hasValidated() && !empty($values)) {
        $this->setData($values);
        if (!$this->isValid()) {
            return;
        }
    } elseif (!$this->isValid) {
        return;
    }

    $filter = $this->getInputFilter();
    $filter->setData($this->data);          //added to fix binding empty data
    switch ($this->bindAs) {
        case FormInterface::VALUES_RAW:
            $data = $filter->getRawValues();
            break;
        case FormInterface::VALUES_NORMALIZED:
        default:
            $data = $filter->getValues();
            break;
    }

    $data = $this->prepareBindData($data, $this->data);

    // If there is a base fieldset, only hydrate beginning from the base fieldset
    if ($this->baseFieldset !== null) {
        $data = $data[$this->baseFieldset->getName()];
        $this->object = $this->baseFieldset->bindValues($data);
    } else {
        $this->object = parent::bindValues($data);
    }
}
```

to be precious it is line no 282 in my zf2.0.6 library

this would fix your problem, this happen only for binded object situation

Comment: Unfortunetly it didn't work. Also I'm not using the `bindValues` but the `bind`-method. Is `bindValues` called internally from `bind`? I couldn't find it in. Also I have no input-filters bound to the form, so I guess that setting the values within the filters doesn't do anything in my case or am I wrong?

Comment: @faileN, nice to know your setHydrator(ObjectProperty) worked, in my case I depend on arrayExchange, I have all my object property as associated array rather than getter/setter, so I am trying to relay on the default ArrayPropery hydrator. It should had work since I had implemented the ArraySerializable interface but didn't, that is why I hacked the code. Thanks for your feedback and let me wait for the zf contributer for my bug reporting

Comment: @faileN, didn't answer your question, the bindValues() method is called from isValid() method when you validate the binded form

Comment: Alright I see. I followed the "Getting Started"-Guide on ZF2. My `Node`-object is an adaption of the `Album`-object they are using. So the fields are stored as properties and not as an array like you do. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, but the solution of Raj is not the right way. This is not a bug as for today the code remains still similar without the 'fix' of Raj, adding the line:

```
$filter->setData($this->data);
```

The main problem here is when you bind an object to the form, the inputfilter is not stored inside the Form object. But called every time from the binded object.

```
public function getInputFilter()
    ...
    $this->object->getInputFilter();
    ...
}
```

My problem was that I created every time a new InputFilter object when the function getInputFilter was called. So I corrected this to be something like below:

```
protected $filter;
...
public function getInputFilter {
    if (!isset($this->filter)) {
        $this->filter = new InputFilter();
        ...
    }
    return $this->filter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today but the fix Raj suggested did not work. I am using the latest version of ZF2 (as of this writing) so I am not totally surprised that it didn't work.

Changing to another Hydrator was not possible as my properties are held in an array. Both the ObjectProperty and ClassMethods hydrators rely on your properties actually being declared (ObjectProperty uses **object_get_vars** and ClassMethods uses **property_exists**). I didn't want to create my own Hydrator (lazy!).

Instead I stuck with the ArraySerializable hydrator and altered my exchangeArray() method slightly.

Originally I had:

```
public function exchangeArray(array $data)
{
    $newData = [];
    foreach($data as $property=>$value)
    {
        if($this->has($property))
        {
            $newData[$property] = $value;
        }
    }
    $this->data = $newData;
}
```

This works fine most of the time, but as you can see it blows away any existing data in $this->data.

I tweaked it as follows:

```
public function exchangeArray(array $data)
{
    $newData = [];
    foreach($data as $property=>$value)
    {
        if($this->has($property))
        {
            $newData[$property] = $value;
        }
    }
    //$this->data = $newData; I changed this line...
    //to...
    $this->data = array_merge($this->data, $newData);
}
```

This preserves any existing keys in $this->data if they are missing from the new data coming in. The only downside to this approach is I can no longer use exchangeArray() to overwrite everything held in $this->data. In my project this approach is a one-off so it is not a big problem. Besides, a new **replaceAllData()** or **overwrite()** method is probably preferred in any case, if for no other reason than being obvious what it does.